# Python threading queue class to another class

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

i have a class that parsing a text from a website, and i have another class which is parsing another text from another website. How can i run this 2 class with multi-threaded/queue?

Sry for bad english, i don't know how to tell this problem clearly.

Here is an example of my code:

```
class my_class1:
   parse an text...
class my_class2:
   parse an text...
```

I want to run this two class at the same time with queue. Thx for help

Comment: You can find a good tutorial [here](https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/)

Comment: Read this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html